# The mapping of CLR type to EDM type is ambiguous because multiple CLR types match the EDM type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

My question is regarding how my application should  change the connection between an online connection with a SQL azure database to offline SQLite database.

I found a way how I can make my application use the online or the offline database.

But when I try to make a variable called Context and return that with one of the two DbContextClass. The switching between the two seems to be something Entity frame does not like.

At first I thought that I could possibly use the same EMDX so that I can use the same DbContextClassname and use the diffrent connection strings in my App.Config but then it gives me this exception :

```
    System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException
    HResult=0x80131939
    Message=Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
    The mapping of CLR type to EDM type is ambiguous because multiple CLR 
    types match the EDM type 'Account'. Previously found CLR type 
    'Domain.Account', newly found CLR type 'SQLiteDataBase.Account'.
```

So should create an interface/abstract Entity frame work that will be inherited by the Online database and the offline database Entity frame work? 
Or is there a more efficient solution?

At the moment I am using a novice configuration of the repository pattern where I would like to switch between the two connections. Is this a proper way of doing things or am I a bit stupid.

```
public abstract class RepositoryBase
{
    protected EntitiesContext Context { get => getConnString();  }

    private DBEntities getConnString()
    {
        DBEntities connString;
        connString = new DBEntities("name=DBEntities");
        if (IsInternetAvailable())
        {
            return connString;
        }
        else
        {
            return connString = new DBEntities("name=SQLiteDBEntities");
        }
    }

    [DllImport("wininet.dll")]
    private extern static bool InternetGetConnectedState(out int description, int reservedValue);

    private static bool IsInternetAvailable()
    {
        int description;
        return InternetGetConnectedState(out description, 0);
    }
}
```

I already have spent around 5 hours on the internet searching for an efficient solution but the solutions always seems to be far to redundant and never solving the problem.

Comment: Terms like "good," "better" and "strange" are not useful unless you can specifically define them.

Comment: Thank you for the tip i will change those words

Comment: You only return `DBEntities`. What's the second context class for?

Comment: The line DBEntities("DBEntities") and DBEntities("SQLiteDBEntities")
was the problem/is the problem

The first one i would like to use for my Azure database
And the second one i would like to use for my SQLite database